# Multithreaded Server via Arduino

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, arduino, client-server

Socket programming question here.

My interface comprises of an Android device(client), A wireless module hosting an access point, and an Arduino Uno(server).

My Android client class works when 1 user connects and sends commands to my Arduino server class.

I want to make my program friendly to many users at the same time.  My server will only read in values from 1 connected client at a time.

After some research I've found that Arduino does not allow multithreading naturally, which is why i've decided to look into a number of libraries.

The Arduino library that I've decided to use for this specific issue is `protothreads`.  Unfortunately, i've been unable to find any examples of creating a server with Arduino to accept a client's commands.  Furthermore I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to make this library work in my favor.

Now for my question,

> How exactly can I allow my Arduino server to constantly listen for
>   incoming messages from more than 1 client device?

Or is there something I can do on the client side that would make this communication possible?

Answer (score 1):

Could you get away with accepting the socket responding and the closing it. Similar to a web page. As not to have multiple sockets open at once. Note uno only has 2k of ram flash goes quick. By one and close each stands alone and naturaly allow many different connections. Just one at a time.

Comment: So after the user connects, and sends a message... Close the port with a ".close()" ?

When will I open it for the next client?  or do I open the port each time a command is detected?

Comment: I wasn't closing my port after a connection so I'll try to do so.. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: This method didn't work, there is about a 2 minute period of time where the wireless module will still think you're connected and will close off to other devices.